# How to flatten nested array of JsonLists

Tags: java

`[[{header=C, value=dsd}, {header=D, value=test}, {header=E, value=e}, {header=F, value=hhh}, {header=G, value=ghgh}]]`

Above is an array of arrays of JsonLists and I need to flatten out the outer array to just be the inner array of JsonLists.

I'd also eventually get only the values out of the JsonList and put those values into it's own separate array :

`[dsd, test, e, hhh, ghgh]`

Comment: I have tried looking at flatmap and I think I am not casting it correctly to JsonList

Comment: Which Json library do you use? Where does JsonList come from?

Comment: It's a custom class:   public JsonList(List<HashMap<String, Object>> list) {
    super(list);
  }
It just stores json into the lists

Comment: Can you also post the details of JsonList class?

Comment: public class JsonList extends ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> {
 public JsonList(List<HashMap<String, Object>> list) { super(list); }

Comment: Hello. You can use [edit] option to clarify your question, like by adding more details. Anyway this JSON array contains only one inner JSON array, so the "flattening" is simply getting/accessing that inner array, something like `JSONArray innerArray = outerArray.get(0);` (depending on your JSON library).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's basically similar to flattening an ArrayList of ArrayList.

```java
final List<Map<String, Object>> result = jsonList.stream()
                .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

and for the values

```java
final List<Object> valueList = result.stream()
                .map(i -> i.get("value"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: How would I change the List<Object> to be a List<String> instead?

Comment: Just do, String.valueOf(i.get(“value”)) and change return type to List<String>

Comment: Do I still need .collect(Collectors.toList())

Comment: Yes, you do need to

Comment: final List<String> valueList = result.stream().map(i -> String.valueOf(i.get("value")).collect(Collectors.toList()));
I have this but it says Cannot resolve method 'collect' in 'String'

Comment: final List<String> valueList = result.stream()
                .map(i -> String.valueOf(i.get("value")))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());